# filehook warning with some packages (currfile, standalone)

Tags: warnings, standalone, currfile, filehook

I noticed that when either of one the two packages `currfile` and `standalone` are loaded, there is a warning issued (using pdflatex or lualatex, at least):

> Macro \InputIfFileExists got redefined after 'filehook' was loaded.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{standalone}     % Uncomment this line.
\usepackage{currfile}       % Or this line.
\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}
```

Is this to be expected, a bug, harmless, or avoidable?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/filehook/issues/4/filehook-needs-more-updating-to-deal-with

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have the same issue as OP, however, after reading through posted issue I am not sure how to resolve this warning (or if there is going to be any solution someday) or if I should just ignore it as I had until now ... ?

Comment: usually it's OK to ignore it (or you could ping that issue tracker and ask for an update....

Comment: I released a fix for this yesterday. Should be available on CTAN and then the distributions soon.

Answer (score 3):

Please update to v0.7 from 2020-02-03 of `filehook`. It fixes this issue.